# php ideas to speed up script for 18000+ calls

Tags: php, curl, optimization

I have a script that makes a few calls. The 1st call gets an array of keys and hash code. Then it goes into a for each and calls out to a 2nd API that will return a list of items that is then passed into a 2nd foreach loop that works with that data and posts to a MySQL database.

It takes 11 hours to run the script. I would appreciate ideas on how I can speed this up. I have looked into multi-processing, but everything I see says making a web request is a bad idea. Any ideas or links are welcome.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60000);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$time = date('Y-m-d');
echo $time;
$time_start = microtime(true);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://zkillboard.com/api/history/20170816/');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
$holder = [];
$i = 0;
$urls = [];
foreach ($obj as $key => $item) {
    $urls[] = ['url' => "https://esi.evetech.net/dev/killmails/{$key}/{$item}/"];
}

$x = 0;
$limit = 15;
$urls = array_slice($urls,0,5);
//foreach (array_chunk($urls, 5, true) as $urlchunk) {
foreach ($urls as $urlchunk) {

        $x ++;
        $aURLs = $urlchunk; // array of URLs
        $mh = curl_multi_init(); // init the curl Multi

        $aCurlHandles = array(); // create an array for the individual curl handles

        foreach ($aURLs as $id => $url) { //add the handles for each url

//            $ch = curl_setup($url);
            $ch = curl_init(); // init curl, and then setup your options
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // returns the result - very important
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // no headers in the output

            $aCurlHandles[$url] = $ch;
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
        }

        $active = null;
        //execute the handles
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

        while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
                do {
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
                } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            }
        }

        /* This is the relevant bit */
        // iterate through the handles and get your content
        foreach ($aCurlHandles as $url => $ch) {
            $html = curl_multi_getcontent($ch); // get the content
            $obj1 = json_decode($html, true);
            $data = str_replace("{", "[", $obj1['victim']);
            $data2 = str_replace("}", "]", $data);

            foreach ($data2['items'] as $value) {
                if (!empty($value['quantity_destroyed'])) {
                    $holder[] = [
                        'item' => $value['item_type_id'],
                        'qty' => $value['quantity_destroyed'],
                        'date' => $time
                    ];
                }
                curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch); // remove the handle (assuming  you are done with it);
            }
            /* End of the relevant bit */

            curl_multi_close($mh); // close the curl multi handler
        }

}
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, 'root', '', 'eve');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully<br>";
$i = 0;
foreach ($holder as $item) {

    $i++;
    $itemCheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM item_temp WHERE itemid ={$item['item']} AND dates='{$item['date']}'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($itemCheck, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($row)) {
        $qty = $row['qty'] + $item['qty'];
        $kills = $row['kills'] + 1;
        $sql = "UPDATE item_temp SET qty='{$qty}' ,kills='{$kills}'  WHERE itemid={$item['item']} AND dates='{$item['date']}'";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO item_temp (itemid, qty, kills, dates)VALUES ('{$item['item']}', '{$item['qty']}', '1', '$time')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    }
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start) / 60;
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> ' . $execution_time . ' Mins';
echo '<b>'. $x;
```

The code has been updated to show `curl_multi` is running at about the same speed. I'm not sure if I'm using it the right way.

Comment: you code does not send request in parallel since you create one multi-exec container per each request. I've updated my answer with sample code based on yours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently each new request is sending only after previous one is done. You can try send several requests in parallel with [curl_multi_*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-getcontent.php) operations. 
Here is example based on your cod

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://zkillboard.com/api/history/20170816/');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
$holder = [];
$i = 0;
$urls = [];
foreach ($obj as $key => $item) {
    $urls[] = "https://esi.evetech.net/dev/killmails/{$key}/{$item}/";
}

$urls = array_slice($urls,0,20); // only first 20 for testing purposes

$mh = curl_multi_init(); // init the curl Multi);
$aCurlHandles = array(); // create an array for the individual curl handles

foreach ($urls as $urlchunk) {
        $ch = curl_init(); // init curl, and then setup your options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlchunk);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // returns the result - very important
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // no headers in the output

        $aCurlHandles[] = $ch;
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
}
$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}


/* This is the relevant bit */
// iterate through the handles and get your content
foreach ($aCurlHandles as $ch) {
    $html = curl_multi_getcontent($ch); // get the content
    $obj1 = json_decode($html, true);
    $holder[]= $obj1['killmail_time'];
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch); // remove the handle (assuming  you are done with it);
}
curl_multi_close($mh); // close the curl multi handler
echo "multi_exec approach \n";
var_dump(sizeof($holder));
echo "\n";
var_dump(array_pop($holder));
echo "\nIt took: " . (microtime(true) - $time_start);

$time_start = microtime(true);
$holder = [];
foreach ($urls as $urlchunk) {
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $urlchunk);
    $result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);
    $holder[] = json_decode($result1, true)['killmail_time'];
}
echo "\n\nsequential approach \n";
var_dump(sizeof($holder));
echo "\n";
var_dump(array_pop($holder));
echo "\nIt took: " . (microtime(true) - $time_start);
```

Be careful and don't try to send *all the requests*(14480 for link you've mentioned) in parallel: you better not to DoS you API, agree?

Comment: running about the same same time

Comment: @ShawnGavaghan This is the right answer, with `curl_multi` handler you will be able to do multiple request in parallel (as php doesn't have multi threading).

Just bear in mind that the requested website might die because of it, there are consequences of such actions (legal ones).

Comment: @LukasS what if the bottleneck is a remote service? Not IO, but a remote service itself that is blocking and single-threaded?

Comment: @zerkms There is no bottleneck here, the speed of the data relies only on his software/server location to the requested website, type of request (if it's static, or calculated with each request), proxies and other elements not seen in his example.

Comment: @LukasS it's just an assumption. If a remote service is blocking and it takes 3 seconds to generate every respond - then `curl_multi` won't help. That's why one should profile/research first, not try random advices. I'm not insisting though - people are free to engineer the way they like ;-)

Comment: @zerkms There is nothing to profile here, anyone running that code will see the time it takes to get response - it's that simple.

API might have some limits built-in, but you can always use techniques to find a way around its limits.

Comment: @LukasS "There is nothing to profile here" --- sure, please don't stop spreading this piece of wisdom around.

Comment: `curl_muti_*` takes ~1 sec for 20 entries while sequential approach leads to 7s delay

Answer (score 0):

- Do not use SELECT * because through this you avoid using possible indices that might exist.
- Use Indices (return to point 1)
- Use IN (...) if possible and maybe break up your logic?
- Use transactions for the updates / inserts? Do you have lock issues on your tables? If so, this would help to break up the flow of the process and you would have more control over what you try to establish; which is difficult to say with the information at hand.

Comment: "Do not use SELECT * because through this you avoid using possible indices that might exist" --- this is not true.

Answer (score -1):

### idea:

if your are not using **PHP7** you should consider upgrading to this version of PHP. The Core (Modules) itself is at least **55%** faster then older versions.